# SSRS - finding the average of field in last X weeks

Tags: reporting-services, average, ssrs-2008-r2

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!WeekEnding.Value)>= DATEADD(Week,-17,GETDATE()),Fields!Hours.Value / 17)
```

I want to find the sum of all hours, in the last 17 weeks then divide by 17 to find the average hours per week.

Thanks in advance

Comment: if you gives us a sample data. that will help to resolve the issue faster.

Comment: does the report only show those 17 weeks of data? or does it show more? please show your query and explain the data that shows if you cant provide it

Comment: so the WeekEnding field is a Datetime e.g. 2017-01-08 00:00:00.000        , I am pulling the data from a view which only has the last 17 weeks in. I want to add columns in a report which shows the Average hours booked over 17 weeks, 16 weeks and so on. The Hours field is a FLOAT.

Answer (score 0):

```
SUM(IIF(Fields!WeekEnding.Value >= DATEADD(Week,-17,GETDATE()),Fields!Hours.Value,0) )/17
```

Comment: Thanks, when I try use this in SSRS, it doesn't like the Week part of the DATEADD - it says Unrecognised Identifier. Any idea why?